# How to open PyQt app from separate python process

Tags: python, pyqt, subprocess

I was wondering if it is possible to open a PyQT app (with a QmainWindow) from a separate python process by running something like the subprocess command. My PyQt app is executable from command line as

```
PyQT_App.py arg1
```

The code for running the app is quite long, but the basic structure is

```
def call_app(arg1):

    class AppWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):

        def __init__(self,arg1):
        do stuff...

    ...


    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    win = AppWindow(arg1)
    print sys.exit(app.exec_())

    return app

if __name__=="__main__":
    call_app(arg1)
```

and I was hoping to run

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(["PyQT_App.py", "arg1"])
```

If I do this and check system monitor, it appears that the app has been launched, but the main window does not appear. Is there an obvious reason this does not work that I am missing? Is there a simple solution?

Comment: do you use `win.show()` or `self.show()` (in init then) ?

Comment: I use self.show()

Comment: I don't know if your process-argument is relevant, but in case you want to use it, you should try `sys.argv` in `AppWindow(...)` or `call_app(...)`. If that is also not your problem, you need to give us more code to provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Your PyQt script may have executable permissions, but it requires a python interpreter to run, and I'm not convinced `subprocess` is always going to be able to come up with the right one, or supply it with the right environment.  I'd make your Python interpreter the first thing in your subprocess argument list before going any further.